# Service Fabric explorer showing endpoint within an anchor tag

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have deployed  a service in the service fabric cluster but i am facing an issue. In the fabric explorer i found the endpoint is  `<a href = "https://a.b.c.d:443" target = "_blank">a.b.c.d:443</a>` instead of just https://a.b.c.d:443
[description of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvSmt.png)

```
<Resources>
        <Endpoints>
            
            <Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Port="443" />
        </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

Can anyone help me where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was a html rendering issue. So instead of displaying as a clickable link it just showed the code as a plain text. It was probably a browser issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).